# In c++, is there a way to jump from one function to another

Tags: c++

In C++ can i jump from inside A() to B() without A() in call stack? Is there anything like `goto` for this case? My situation is I should destroy an object at the end of one of its function.

```
class timeBomb{
public:
  void detonate(int time){
    sleep(time);
    goto this->blast(this); //something like that
  };
  timeBomb();

  static void blast(timeBomb bomb){
    delete bomb;
  }
}

int main(){
  timeBomb *myBomb = new timeBomb();
  myBomb->detonate(2);
  return 0;
}
```

I could have gone away with `delete this;`. but in my code on a specific condition the constructor itself has to call a function which in turn call a function like detonate.

to solve my problem i could have asked can i abort creating an object. but i found jumping form one function to another avoiding parent function in call stack fascinating and useful.

Comment: No, you can't use `goto` to go to a different function.

Comment: That looks extremely *wrong*

Comment: Think you can use setjmp and longjmp but you shouldn't.

Comment: You can explicitly destroy and delete the object: `sleep(time); ~timeBomb(); delete this;` -- although this code looks very confused and I don't think that is the solution to your problem.

Comment: You *call* the function?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - that's because it is extremely wrong.

Comment: At the very least, if your class contains a member that says `delete this;`, it should have a private (or protected) destructor.

Comment: to solve my problem i could have asked can i abort creating an object. but i found jumping form one function to another avoiding parent function in call stack fascinating and useful. At least i wanna ask can i abort object creation?

Comment: @neckTwi throw an exception. That's how you abort object construction. Next time, you can try describing your problem (i.e. "I want to abort object construction") instead of describing your crazy solution.

Comment: It's not very fascinating when it has to be maintained.   Please stop attempting/doing weird things.

Answer (score 1):

You can "go back in time" to a place where you've been before using `setjmp` and `longjmp`, but there is nothing to jump to a random new location in the code (aside from various system dependent things, like using inline assembler or some such - and this would still be hard to make very generic, as you need to care for stack cleanup and other things like that).

Answer (score 1):

If you have common functionality then make a (`private`) method and call it from all methods that need that functionality:

```
class timeBomb {
public:
  void detonate(int time){
    sleep(time);
    blast();
  };
  timeBomb();

private:
  void blast(){
    delete this;   // Very dangerous!
  }
};
```